# Retrieve JSON from URL with Python

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I want to retrieve a JSON from a website, but somehow it doesn't work. I can see the JSON on the website (developer tools) and validated it, all fine.

Here's my code:

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

try:
    response = requests.get('https://www.landal.de/parks/beach-park-texel/unterkunfte/4bl')
    response.raise_for_status()
    # access JSOn content
    jsonResponse = response.json()
    print("Entire JSON response")
    print(jsonResponse)

except HTTPError as http_err:
    print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')
except Exception as err:
    print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')
```

Here's the error:

```
Other error occurred: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 2)
```

As I read through many question, I sense it's the website.

Comment: print(response.headers.get('Content-Type')) tells us that the response content is text/html; charset=utf-8 and not JSON. Which is why you are getting error while converting it to JSON. If you try print(response.text)  you will see an html response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Json data from the page, use `POST` with a payload:

```py
import requests

url = "https://www.landal.de/parks/beach-park-texel/unterkunfte/4bl"

payload = {
    "arrivalDate": "20-11-2023",
    "departureDate": "24-11-2023",
    "numberOfDays": "5",
    "stayType": "925",
    "travelGroup[0][Id]": "18-120",
    "travelGroup[0][Amount]": "0",
    "travelGroup[1][Id]": "3-17",
    "travelGroup[1][Amount]": "0",
    "travelGroup[2][Id]": "0-2",
    "travelGroup[2][Amount]": "0",
    "travelGroup[3][Id]": "pets",
    "travelGroup[3][Amount]": "0",
    "travelGroupCombiEnabled": "false",
    "scController": "PriceGridComponent",
    "scAction": "Get",
}

data = requests.post(url, data=payload).json()
print(data)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "IsSuccess": True,
    "searchResult": {
        "arrivalDates": [
            {
                "Year": "2023",
                "Month": "10",
                "DaysWithCount": [
                    {"Day": "06", "ParkCount": 1, "Durations": [3]},
                    {"Day": "13", "ParkCount": 1, "Durations": [3, 7, 10, 14]},
                    {"Day": "16", "ParkCount": 1, "Durations": [4, 7, 11, 14]},
                    {"Day": "20", "ParkCount": 1, "Durations": [3, 7, 10]},
                    {"Day": "23", "ParkCount": 1, "Durations": [4, 7]},
                    {"Day": "27", "ParkCount": 1, "Durations": [3]},
                ],
            },

...
```